# Alexa Smart Home Skill for Humidity and/or brightness?

Tags: rest, alexa-skills-kit, brightness, alexa-smart-home-skill

I am currently working with Alexa Smart Home Skills and implementing an interface to various data that I already have in a database. For example, this was no problem for the temperature, since there is a known API for this:
https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/device-apis/alexa-temperaturesensor.html

But now I wonder why there is no API for humidity or brightness? Of course I could also use a PercentageController for this, but that would probably eliminate the pleasant voice support of Alexa? It's important to me that I don't need an unnecessary activation word, as would be the case with normal skills.

Is there any other way to query humidity or brightness via Alexa?

Thank you very much and best regards!

Answer (score 0):

There is API for brightness : https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/device-apis/alexa-brightnesscontroller.html

Could not find an API for humidity. You will have to go with percentage controller only.

Comment: I mean the ambient brightness and not setting the brightness of a lamp